form_with issues with ":model"
I've looked everywhere I could before coming here but here's a weird one. I'm very new to RoR so wouldn't doubt if it's something obvious I'm missing.
I'm receiving an error "Passed nil to the :model argument, expect an object or false" for a form that Is used to login a user.
Weird thing is that I solved it somehow by accident by making a typo of the word ":model"
I found out that I can use literally any other word except ":model and it works flawlessly."
It's bugging me because I know this is not the correct way to do this.
Here is my form with errors:
<h1> Log in </h1>

<%= form_with model: @user, url: session_path do |form| %>
  <div>
    <%= form.label :email %>
    <%= form.email_field :email %>
  </div>

   <div>
    <%= form.label :password %>
    <%= form.password_field :password %>
   </div>
  
    <div>
      <%= form.submit "Log in" %>
    </div>
<%end%>



Form that works PERFECTLY with the typo of model.
<h1> Log in </h1>

<%= form_with mode: @user, url: session_path do |form| %>
  <div>
    <%= form.label :email %>
    <%= form.email_field :email %>
  </div>

   <div>
    <%= form.label :password %>
    <%= form.password_field :password %>
   </div>
  
    <div>
      <%= form.submit "Log in" %>
    </div>
<%end%>


sessions controller
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  # Creates a new session for a user
  def create
    if user = User.authenticate_by(email: params[:email], password: params[:password])
      login user
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Signed in"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Invalid email or password"
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end


  def destroy
    logout current_user
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "logged out"
  end
end


This works because the form is not passing the model name back — and your controller is not checking for the model name. Using the model name, you would have to use params[:user][:email], etc.

Also, you will want to use strong parameters https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

@dbugger you might want to read up on what strong parameters actually do. They just prevent mass assignment vulnerabilites by requiring that you pass the params through whitelist. If you're accessing the param keys one by one like in this case there is no potential mass assignment vulnerability and it won't actually do anything of note.

@max -- I know how they work -- thank you -- just a good practice to get into and something that would have pointed out the mismatch here

@dbugger I really don't agree in this case since only two parameters are used and there really isn't any reason to nest the parameters. The error should be caught with tests instead of by adding needless complexity.

There really is no mystery here.
The signature of the form_with method is:
form_with(model: false, scope: nil, url: nil, format: nil, **options, &block)

The method has four named keyword arguments which are optional as well as a double splat argument which gathers up any remaining arguments. If passed Rails will ensure that the model: argument is not nil - to prevent nil errors.
Ruby doesn't warm you or raise an error if you access an instance variable that isn't set. @user is not being set anywhere in your code. I would put the work in the learn to use debug to set breakpoints so that you can actually diagnose nil errors instead of being completely lost every time it happens (it happens a lot - especially when you're new).
By changing the call to:
<%= form_with mode: @user, url: session_path do |form| %>

You're really just sweeping that bug under the carpet. The code doesn't actually work "perfectly" - it's just that the bug is benign since the mode: nil keyword argument is ignored. Since you're passing the url: option the model isn't actually needed.
Even if the bug is benign you're still leaving a footgun in place as if someone fixes the misspelling and passes a user instance your controller would break as :user would be used as the scope option and the inputs would be serialized as user[email] and user[password] instead of "flat" parameters at the root level.
All you actually need here is:
<%= form_with url: session_path do |form| %>

You're not actually creating an instance of user or binding the form input to a user so passing a model doesn't make that much sense.

It looks like you have not initialized @user instance variable and please find the solution below:
Intead of this:
def new
end

Use this
def new
  @user = User.new
end

